# WooCommerce showing active product categories on single product page

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using this code to show a list of product child-categories of a specific category (Parent ID = 173) on my sidebar on a single product page.

```
<?php
    $orderby = 'name';
    $order = 'asc';
    $hide_empty = false ;
    $cat_args = array(
                'parent'     => 173,
                'orderby'    => $orderby,
        'order'      => $order,
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,

    );
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
    if( !empty($product_categories) ){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
            echo $category->name;
            echo '</a>';
            echo '<li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

However it's showing ALL child-categories that exist on my website. I would like to just show the active ones that this product is in. How can I tweak this to just show the active ones?

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly - `hide_empty => true`
Look in the codex for possible args for **get_terms**:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/